# Get certain text in string powershell

Tags: string, powershell

I want to get "localhost" (or whatever text) inside this string:

```
XML-Execute-Result: <host>localhost</host>
```

I want a general method, like a way to reuse an expression value 
(like with sed in linux)

```
sed 's/*[0-9]$/\$&/'
```

Thank you very much for any reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "XML-Execute-Result: <host>localhost</host>"
if ($text -match "\<host\>(?<host>.*?)\</host\>")
{
    $myhost = $matches.host
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
PS> if ($text -match "<host>(.*?)</host>") {$matches[1]}
localhost
```